# JPA 2.0 Hibernate 4.1.2 Entity not found even to be persisted before

Tags: hibernate, jpa, merge, jpa-2.0, persist

i have some problem with JPA persist() and merge() method.

In my code, i do.

```
Foo foo = new Foo("abc");
fooService.persist(foo)
..(blabla)
foo.setField("123");
fooService.merge(foo);
```

This code create two rows foo in my database MySQL.

Once with foo (abc, null) and another with foo (abc, 123).

When i looked in mysql query, the merge(foo) did not found the object foo in database so it create new row with updated data.
Note that fooService.persist(foo) is executed in a transaction and fooService.merge(foo) is executed in another transaction. I already call flush() after persist but it doesn't work.

Please find below my code (i do not detail all)

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private String field;
  public Foo(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }
}

public class FooServiceImpl {

  @Autowired
  FooDao fooDao;

  @Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRED)
  public void persist(Foo foo){
    fooDao.persist(foo);
  }


  @Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRED)
  public Foo merge(Foo foo){
    return fooDao.merge(foo);
  }
}

public class FooDaoImpl {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public void persist(Foo foo){
    this.entityManager.persist(foo);
    this.entityManager.flush();
  }

  public Foo merge(Foo foo){
    return this.entityManager.merge(foo);
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

transaction is commited when method finishes, so when you call persist, it's not actually persisted at that moment.
try to change your logic so that you call only once persist at the end, and when entity is not going to be updated anymore (don't use merge).